# A commutative ring whose all localizations are fields

Tags: commutative-algebra

If $A$ is a ring such that $A_{p}$ is a field for every prime ideal $p\subseteq A$, is $A$ a field?

Comment: Yes, I would and perhaps even should and could. Would ya? Or in other words: what are your thoughts, your effort, your ideas on this? Note that the other direction of the claim is true, so this would be an iff claim...

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.  Take $A$ to be a product of two fields.  Notice that, here, $A$ isn't even a domain.  So, we've shown not only that being a field isn't a local property, but being a domain isn't a local property, either.